# One Row For Label & DateTime Box

Tags: php, html, joomla

In my sample on phpfiddle my syntax below produces the start date and finish date on one line, but when I put this into Joomla the start date is on one row and the finish date is on a row under it.

Why is Joomla throwing off the formatting?

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
<div style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 40px; width: 650px;"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            Begin Date: <input type="date" name="begindate" />
            Finish Date: <input type="date" name="finishdate" />
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I haven't used Joomla before, but if styles are appearing differently, check to make sure that there is not a stylesheet that's not automatically being included that makes `input` elements display as a block, rather than inline.

Comment: I second @RobertCalove's comment - and you can also use your browser's Developer console to inspect the DOM nodes... Inspect one of the dates in the DOM inspector and that should allow you to see which stylesheet is doing it